# Обновление своего deb-пакета

Tags: debian, dpkg, deb

Относительно недавно сформировал свой собственный пакет files_1.deb для debian для установки некоторых файлов на удаленные сервера филиалов. Файлы лежат в корне пакета. Теперь создаю еще один deb-пакет, скажем, files_2.deb, в котором содержатся дополнительные файлы, также в корне пакета.

Но когда выполняют команду `dpkg -i files_2.deb` на удаленном сервере, то неожиданно удаляются на сервере файлы, которые были в files_1.deb.

Как это можно запретить? Файла postrm нет в обоих пакетах, чтобы было удаление.

Answer (score 3):

скорее всего, удаляются не файлы, а обновляется пакет.

вероятно, вы назвали пакеты именами *files_1* и *files_2*. а так как символ подчёркивания [не является допустимым в имени пакета](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_debian_package_file_names), но служит для отделения имени пакета от опционального поля эпохи (*epoch*), то, с точки зрения пакетного менеджера, это один и тот же пакет (только с разными эпохами).

поэтому пакет *files* (с эпохой *2*) при установке и **заменяет** одноимённый пакет *files* (с эпохой *1*).

---

если вы хотите, чтобы пристутствовали файлы из обоих пакетов, самое логичное — установить **оба** этих пакета. естественно, они должны носить **разные** имена.

Comment: Мне и нужно обновление, но чтобы файлы не удалялись, т.к. видимо при обновление идет удаление файлов, которые были из него скопированы. Наткнулся что в этом может помочь утилита dpkg-divert в файле preinst, но никак не могу понять как ей воспользоваться, точнее не понимаю)

Comment: система управления пакетами — это всё-таки далеко не система управления версиями файлов. при обновлении пакета файлы старой версии удаляются (конфигурационные — переименовываются, если не сконфигурировано иначе). механизм же [диверсий](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-diversions.html) придуман для возможности подмены файлов *одного установленного* пакета файлами *другого устанавленного* пакета.

Comment: @nerik, я дополнил ответ.